# Get value of property in nested object using only a string to navigate the object

Tags: c#

Say i have Object1 which has a list of Object2 which has Object3, which has Property1 which i want the value of.  Is it possible to have a string in my database like "Object1.Object2[0].Object3.Property1" and then somehow use that within code to navigate that object and get the value for a property i want?  I am getting my object i want to navigate to from another api and i basically want to look in my database and  see property1 must be > 10 and then dynamically be able navigate that object so i can see if the value in my object passes my criteria in my database.  I want to be able to just use database values for this so we can add fields to our database without updating our code.  Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but you'll have to write the code yourself to accomplish it. You'll have to parse the string into a sequence of accesses and then execute those accesses against the object. How you do this depends on the types of the objects.

Comment: @cdhowie is correct. For the the individual property accesses, the guide here on using reflection should be useful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196991/get-property-value-from-string-using-reflection-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a nuget package to do exactly what i wanted.  https://github.com/Domysee/Pather.CSharp

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is definitely possible. You'll want `Object1` to be a dynamic object, so that you can access its properties using variables e.g. `Object1["Object2"][0]`. Then all you need is to work out a consistent format for your database strings, with your example you could split by `.` and use a loop to access and store each property in the result successively.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142495/deserialize-json-into-c-sharp-dynamic-object) question for info on dynamic objects from JSON (assuming that's the format you receive it in from your API) or if you'd prefer to use reflection, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196991/get-property-value-from-string-using-reflection-in-c-sharp) question has info about that.